# Why is the torque of a rolling hexagon about axis equal to 0?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, torque

In the International Physics Olympiad problem 1998: rolling of a hexagonal prism:

[image]

it states that conservation of angular momentum is applicable since the total external torque is 0. How is this the case? Wouldn't there be a torque due to the gravitational force about the axis of rotation of the hexagon? Is it because they take the torque around the center of mass - which cancels out the gravitational force causing the torque?

Comment: Related [Motion of Hexagonal Pencil on an inclined Plane](https://arxiv.org/vc/arxiv/papers/0706/0706.3431v2.pdf) and [Olypiad solution](https://ipho.olimpicos.net/pdf/IPhO_1998_S1.pdf)

Comment: Yes but it doesn't explain the torque being 0

Comment: The force on the hexagon due to the plane acts at the same point (corner of hexagon) as the point about which the angular momentum is found.

Comment: what is the force due to the plane? Is it friction? Normal force? Why does it have to act only on the corner of the hexagon?

Comment: http://hkpho.phys.ust.hk/Protected/Past_notes/3%20Angular%20momentum_HKBU.pdf

Comment: I would begin with analyzing the problem with a circular object. If you think of a circle as a polygon with "infinite" sides, then you can see the difference in behavior of the center of mass (if this is your chosen axis of rotation) between a 6 sided polygon and a circle or infinite sided polygon. That may provide some insight.

Comment: Keep the question open. It is a valid well-formed question.

Comment: I don't know how.